# Condition within for loop is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to run a conditional for loop on a dataframe. If the condition is not met, then the last row is appended to the result dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(100,3)), columns=['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3'])

split_df = [df[i:i+12] for i in range(0, len(df))]

result = []
for i in split_df:
    if i == 0:
        result = split_df[i]
    else:
        last_row = split_df[i].tail(1)
        result = result.append(last_row, ignore_index=True)
```

For `If i == 0:`, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How do I get around this?

Comment: What do you think `i` is when you check `i == 0`?

Comment: FYI `split_df = [df[i:i+12] for i in range(0, len(df))]` is equivalent to `df.rolling(12)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` is a `DataFrame`, because you're looping over a list of `DataFrame`s. You probably want to  write the loop like this:

```py
for i, df in enumerate(split_df):
    if i == 0:
        result = df
    else:
        last_row = df.tail(1)
        result.append(last_row, ignore_index=True)
```

Also note that you don't want to write `result = result.append(...)` - rather, you'd just write `result.append(...)` because `append()` modifies the loop *in-place*, and it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Thank you, this fixes the issue. I did not realize I had to enumerate the df.